# iCloud Demo Sourcecode for iOS and OSX

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

I want to build an iOS and Mac App that stay in sync using iCloud.

I only found an apple demo project for the mac: [PackagedDocument](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/PackagedDocument/Introduction/Intro.html)

Now I am looking for a simple demo app that includes both an iOS app and a Mac app. I have seen this on a WWDC Demo but this demo does not seem to be part of the demos that ship with Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Tutorial at location

http://www.appcoda.com/icloud-programming-ios-intro-tutorial/

as a starting point

Comment: This does not include the Mac version though but a nice tutorial all the same. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found WWDC12 Sample code which contains an App for both the Mac and iOS:

https://github.com/jab5990/TestCDiCloud

[image: mac-app]
[image: iphone-app]